# Start-Stop button in Kivy Python

Tags: python, kivy

I need to make a button that starts main function and has a "start" text by default. After being pressed it should not only change the text to "stop", which is easy, but it also should stop the application. The problem is, I don't understand how to implement this. I know how to change the text,  I found a stop method in docs, but I don't know how to change functionality. I think I can use state here, but I have errors.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "stop the application"? It probably isn't actually stopping the application, because you suggest the button should still be displayed.

Comment: I mean stop the main function of the app.

Comment: And what do you mean by that? What is the "main function"?

Comment: Well, as I understand, "run" method starts my app. But the app (like vpn apps) should be started only when the button "start" is pressed. So when I call the the "run" method I should only see the "welcome page" with this button and settings. The main function is the logic and it is called when the button is pressed. I can't understand how to make a button that would start and stop my functionality. Maybe I should call on press depending on button's status?

Comment: The `run` method of your `App` just starts the `kivy` event loop that processes events and keeps the gui up to date. Nothing else is started until you cause it to be started.

Comment: Yeah, but the idea is to create a method that starts after button1 is pressed (i can bind it) and that also works until the button 2 is pressed. I don't know hot to do the second part.